# Convolutional Autoencoder in Pytorch for Dummies

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am here to ask some more general questions about Pytorch and Convolutional Autoencoders.

1. If I only use Convolutional Layers (FCN), do I even have to care about the input shape? And then how do I choose the number of featuremaps best?
2. Does a ConvTranspose2d Layer automatically unpool?
3. Can you spot any errors or unconventional code in my example?

By the way, I want to make a symmetrical Convolutional Autoencoder to colorize black and white images with different image sizes.

```py
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential (
        # conv 1
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),  # 1/2
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),

        # conv 2
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),  # 1/4
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),

        # conv 3
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),  # 1/8
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),

        # conv 4
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),  #1/16
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    )


    self.encoder = nn.Sequential (
        # conv 5
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),

        # conv 6
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),

        # conv 7
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU,
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),

        # conv 8
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.Softmax()
    )

    def forward(self, x):
        h = x
        h = self.encoder(h)
        h = self.decoder(h)
        return h
```

Comment: One problem with this code is that the batch norm layer follows a convolution with bias turned on. You should set the bias=False in the convolutions that come before the batch norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, you don't need to care about input width and height with a fully convolutional model. But should probably ensure that each downsampling operation in the encoder is matched by a corresponding upsampling operation in the decoder.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by unpooling. If you mean upsampling (increasing spatial dimensions), then this is what the `stride` parameter is for. In PyTorch, a transpose convolution with `stride=2` will upsample twice. Note, however, that instead of a transpose convolution, many practitioners prefer to use bilinear upsampling followed by a regular convolution. [This](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) is one reason why.

If, on the other hand, you mean actual unpooling, then you should look at the documentation of [`torch.MaxUnpool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#maxunpool2d). You need to collect maximal value indices from the `MaxPool2d` operation and feed them into `MaxUnpool2d`.

The general consensus seems to be that you should *increase* the number of feature maps as you downsample. Your code appears to do the reverse. Consecutive powers of 2 seem like a good place to start. It's hard to suggest a better rule of thumb. You probably need to experiment a little.

In other notes, I'm not sure why you apply softmax to the encoder output.